# Aligning a caption div inside the orbit plugin - zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, orbit

I am trying to do a responsive layout with the orbit (zurb foundation framework) and I want to add a div above pictures with dynamic content.
My biggest problem is that when the browser resizes, the rectangular div goes out of the picture.
Any Idea?

here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bonomi/Tw53e/

here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12">
        <ul data-orbit>
            <li>
                <img src="http://www.tamurilart.com/art-gallery/fractals/800x600/birth-of-a-galaxy-800x600.jpg" alt="slide 1">
                <div class="orbit-caption">
                Caption 1
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="orbit-caption">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.orbit-container ul li img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.orbit-next, .orbit-prev {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.custom-caption {
    display: block;
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want the div to be?

Comment: Centered in the middle of the picture, in a layer over and I want it re-sizable like the picture.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw53e/1/ like this?

Comment: It's almost that, but if you re-size the browser the rectangle is aligned with the "orbit-container" div, not with the image. Is it possible to align it with the image? try to add some text do the rectangle, in the right and left side.